# import xgboost as xgb not working in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, xgboost

I am trying to using XGBoost and have installed it fine, but when I try to run it on Anaconda with:

```
import xgboost as xgb
```

It tells me "No module named XGBoost."

when I run the same import in Idle it imports fine.

I originally installed it using command prompt with the pip command

```
pip install xgboost
```

It seemed to install fine.

Since failing to work in Anaconda I have tried installing it in the Anaconda Prompt using the same pip command and it told me it was already installed. I have also tried downloading the wheel and installing it using that in Anaconda Prompt and that said it was already installed. Finally I have also reset Anaconda and reset my computer and none of that worked.

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. How exactly are you running the program? Are you running it with the correct Python installation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply AMC. At the moment I am just trying to run import xgboost on Anacondathe version of Python is 3.7. Is there any other information I could provide to be more specific?

Comment: _How exactly are you running the program? Are you running it with the correct Python installation?_

Comment: What are the contents of the Conda environment? Have you tried installing the library through Conda, rather than with pip? (see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)

Comment: I am running it in the Python installation 3.7 in anaconda

Comment: If I go to anaconda comand prompt and type conda install xgboost it says conda is not recognized as an internal or external command. Is that how your meant to install with conda?

Comment: Yes, I meant installing through/using Conda. If you do some research for that error message there should be plenty of solutions available.